# JS and Google Map - Centering map on marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-embed

I`m having trouble  to center the map with the marker, here is the b*:

```
           <iframe
          width="555"
          height="450"
          frameborder="0" style="border:0"
          src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=***&q=<? echo urlencode($address); ?>&zoom=14">
        </iframe>
```

The map loads, but with the marker at the left top of the screen, so the user have to use the mouse to really put the desired area on the screen.

Anybody knows how to center the map with the marker position?

Sorry for the repeated question, but the anwsers i saw so far did not  worked in my case.

Comment: You can specify a `center` URL attribute if you have a latitude and longitude.  See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#optional_parameters  However I would have expected the `place` mode to automatically center the map on your address

Comment: saddly i don`t have lat and lon... it`s a dynamic page and the location will change with the address gave by the page admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saddly i wasn`t able to make it work with the iframe, instead i used the JS way...

JS:

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.730885,-73.997383);
var mapOptions = {
    scrollwheel: true,
    zoom: 15,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions );

var address = 'address string';
geocoder.geocode(
{ 'address': address},
function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

        var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            draggable: true,
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
    } else {
        //alert('Location not found.');
    }
}
);
```

HTMl:

```
        <div id="map-canvas">
            <div id="map" style="width:555px;height:450px;"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

wich i was avoiding to use cause lead to another problem with CSS display as null when page loaded... but that was solved to (no reason to explain how cause wasn`t involved in the question ^^").

Anyway, if anyone find i solution for the iframe example, still would be interesting... but that`s all folks o/